# Chutzpah not detecting TypeScript tests which contain enums

Tags: visual-studio-2012, enums, typescript, qunit, chutzpah

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2012, Chutzpah and QUnit for unit testing on a TypeScript project and have encountered a problem.

Chutzpah successfully detects the following code and lists the test in the Test Explorer:

```
/// <reference path="../../modules/qunit.d.ts" />
test("A Test", () => { });
```

However, if I reference any TypeScript which makes use of an enum, no test is detected.

For example:

```
/// <reference path="../../modules/qunit.d.ts" />
module A {
    export enum B { };
    export var C: B;
}

test("A Test", () => { });
```

I am using:

- VS2012 Update 4
- Chutzpah 3.0.0
- Typescript 0.9.5
- QUnit 1.12.0

Is this a bug with Chutzpah Typescript support for enums?

Comment: As an alternative you could try this other extension specifically for TypeScript http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34b2cc77-971a-4226-8f93-54518a7917ae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in version 3.0.0. It is now fixed in the 3.0.1 release. If you upgrade this should work.